How to linearize the term in objective function not the constraints
I have tried to linearize the term product of two continuous variables in the objective function by McCormick envelopes in GAMS. However, the model does not have the constraints for the product so after using the linearization, I got the result different from the original one.
The original model:
min Ob = sum(t, (another terms) + x(t)*y(t))  
s.t. x(t) <= u(t) * x_max
     x(t) >= u(t) * x_min
     y(t) <= u(t) * y_max
     y(t) >= u(t) * y_min
     other constraints but not any related to the product of x and y

Where u(t) is a binary variable, u = 1 means x and y are used that time step t and 0 otherwise.
My linearization:
min Ob = (another terms) + z
s.t. z(t) >= x_min * y(t) + y_min * x(t) - x_min * y_min
     z(t) >= x_max * y(t) + y_max * x(t) - x_max * y_max  
     z(t) <= x_min * y(t) + y_max * x(t) - x_min * y_max
     z(t) <= x_max * y(t) + y_min * x(t) - x_max * y_min
     x(t) <= u(t) * x_max
     x(t) >= u(t) * x_min
     y(t) <= u(t) * y_max
     y(t) >= u(t) * y_min
     other constraints but not any related to the product of x and y

Even though the value of u is not binary anymore, it turns into continuous.
Example of the value of u after solving u(t1) = 0.295, u(t2) = 0.295, u(t3) = 0.295, u(t4) = 0.200 ... .
Please help me with any ideas to fix the model.
Thank you all for your time.
I try to solve the non-linear problem by linearizing the product term.

Is u(t) a binary variables? Then, if the solution is feasible, it should assume only binary variables. Note that MINLP solvers are developed not just for fun. They actually serve a purpose.

I create u(t) as the binary, but after solving, the value of u(t) is continuous instead of binary as I provided u(t1) = 0.295, u(t2) = 0.295, u(t3) = 0.295, u(t4) = 0.200 ... .  I am not sure why is it.

The listing file shows the model and solver status. You should always check that. Always. You may want to read first the GAMS tutorial.
